# Axios Error: Network error with javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

I'm new to using axios and stripe and I'm encountering some issues. When I try to make a post request with axios I receive this error:

[image: This is the error I receive when making a post request]

Perhaps my endpoint is incorrect. I'm not sure. Here is my code in Payments.js:

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import CheckoutProduct from './CheckoutProduct';
import './Payment.css';
import {useStateValue} from './StateProvider';
import {Link, useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
import {CardElement, useStripe, useElements} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import CurrencyFormat from "react-currency-format";
import {getBasketTotal} from "./reducer";
import axios from './axios';


function Payment() {

    const [{basket,user}, dispatch] = useStateValue();
    const history = useHistory();

    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();
    
    const [succeeded, setSucceeded] = useState(false);
    const [processing, setProcessing] = useState("");
    const [error,setError] = useState(null);
    const [disabled,setDisabled] = useState(true);
    const [clientSecret,setClientSecret] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
       
        const getClientSecret = async () => {
            try {
            const response = await axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: `/payments/create?total=${getBasketTotal(basket)*100}` 
            });
           
            console.log("THIS IS THE RESPONSE", response);
            setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret);
                 }
              catch (error) {
                console.log("THIS IS THE ERROR", error);
                }
        }
        
        getClientSecret();

    },[basket]);

    console.log('THE CLIENT SECRET >>>', clientSecret);
```

And here is my middleware code in index.js:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const stripe = require("stripe")("/* my secret stripe api key is here */");

const app = express();

app.use(cors({origin: true}));
app.use(express.json());


app.get("/", (request, response) => response.status(200).send
("hello world"));

app.post("/payments/create/", async (request, response) => {
  const total = request.params.total;
  console.log("Payment Request Received >>>", total);

  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount:total, 
    currency:"usd",
    });
    response.status(201).send({
        clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
    })
});

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Here is my axios.js file:

```
import axios from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:5001/clone-bfd8a/us-central1/api'
});

export default instance;
```

I was reviewing the post endpoint in my Payments.js file to see if it was correct. Then I checked my middleware in index.js to see if it coincided with my endpoint in Payment.js. To me, the endpoints seem correct. I was expecting that the application show the `clientSecret` but instead I got the axios Network Error.

I also received this error in my terminal:
[image: It states that the 'amount' parameter is missing]

It says the 'amount' parameter is missing but I'm not sure why it says that because I included it in the post middleware route.

I think the error may be in Payments.js where it says:

```
setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret);
```

Maybe `response.data.clientSecret` doesn't exist.

I'm also thinking the error is in index.js where it says:

```
clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
```

Perhaps `client_secret` is not defined by stripe. I'm not sure. Any ideas why I'm receiving this Axios network error? Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

UPDATE:

So it seems to be kind of working now. I changed `req.params.total` to `req.query.total` in my middleware post route in index.js:

[image]

But it still seems to be acting kind of weird: When I first start the application, I get the error as mentioned above. However, after waiting a couple of minutes, I am able to successfully make a post request with axios. Is it possible that the frontend and backend need to take some time to be synchronized? Could it be that the error is happening because the `basket` variable is empty at first and then axios tries to make the post request? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think your endpoint configuration should be

```
app.post("/payments/create", ...
```

Instead of

```
app.post("/payments/create/", ...
```

Also, your endpoint is dependent on the execution of a 3rd-party service (stripe) so you better add some error handling as well. In short:

```
app.post("/payments/create/", async (request, response) => {
  const total = request.params.total;
  console.log("Payment Request Received >>>", total);
  try {
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount:total, 
      currency:"usd",
      });
      response.status(201).send({
        clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
      });
  } catch (error) {
      response.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is of stripe,  total must be in cents (100 for $ 1 dolar)

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
          amount: total,
          currency: "usd",
          payment_method_types: ["card"],
          description: "Buy a xxxx"
          confirm: true,
          });

          if (paymentIntent) {
              if (
                  paymentIntent.status === "requires_action" &&
                  paymentIntent.next_action.type === "use_stripe_sdk"
                  ) {

                    response.status(201).send({
                       clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
                    })

                  } else if (paymentIntent.status === "succeeded") {
                         
                     response.status(200).send({
                      message: "success"
                     })
                      
                  } else {
                     console.log("Invalid PaymentIntent status");
                  }
             } else {
                   console.log("Invalid PaymentIntent status");
             }
```

Please validate error of paymentIntent (Stripe), when an error appears in stripe, axios cannot continue and show Network Error.

Comment: Hey Camilo thanks for your comment! I made sure the total was in cents because in my Payments.js I multiplied `/payments/create?total=${getBasketTotal(basket)*100} `. So im not sure why Stripe is giving an error

Comment: This error stripe: "parameter missing"  Some parameter is missing, but I'm wondering if the required are already set and only the optional ones remain. I use : amount, currency, payment_method_types, customer, payment_method, description, metadata, confirm. Maybe useEffect is executed more than once and the first time sends empty values

Comment: Ok well I got it to kind of work. I made an update on my post. It seems that I got it to kind of work. Im able to successfully make a post request. But it doesn't seem to work when I first run my application. Only when I make some coding change in the useEffect() function does it start to work. Or if I wait a couple of minutes, it begins to work. Does it have something to do when the `basket` variable is empty? Or does the frontend and backend need some time to be synchronized?